# How do I sort data from file by member of a struct? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

Here I have a program that reads in some employee data from a file and stores them in an array of structs. What I am trying to do with the "sort_by_age" function is to sort this data based on date of birth to where the data is listed from oldest employee to youngest employee.The "read_file" function works fine, and the program compiles fine, but the output is incorrect, the program doesnt sort the data properly as i would like. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Heres a few lines from the file to give an idea of the format

```
114680858 19670607 Matilda Vincent MI

114930037 19471024 Desdemona Hanover ID

115550206 19790110 Xanadu Perlman ND

116520629 19630921 Alexander Hall SD
```

so for example if this was all the lines in the file(its not), i want it to sort Desdemona's info first, then alexander's, then, matilda's, then xanadu's.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

struct employees // employee data
{
int ss_number;//social security
int dob;//date of birth YYYY/MM/DD Ex.) 19870314=1987/03/14
string f_name;
string l_name;
string state; //state of residence };


void read_file()//read file into array of 1000 structs
{
ifstream data("/home/www/class/een118/labs/database1.txt");
employees array[100]
if(!data.fail())
{
int i;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
data>>array[i].ss_number
>>array[i].dob
>>array[i].f_name
>>array[i].l_name
>>array[i].state;
}
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
cout<<array[i].ss_number>>" "<<array[i].dob>>" "<<array[i].f_name>>" "<<
array[i].l_name>>" "<<array[i].state;
}}}


void print_person(employees e)
{
cout<<e.ss_number>>" "<<e.dob>>" "<<e.f_name>>" "<<e.l_name>>" "<<e.state;
}

void sort_by_age(employees array[])
{
employees temp;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
for(int j=i+1;j<100;j++)
{
if(array[j].dob<array[i].dob)
{
temp=array[i];
array[i]=array[j];
array[j]=temp;}
print_person(array[j]);
cout<<"\n";}}}





int main()
{
employees array[100];
read_file(array);
sort_by_age(array);
}
```

Comment: Wasn't that answered here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187954/how-do-i-sort-the-employee-data-in-this-program-from-oldest-person-to-youngest-p

Comment: i got all kinds of errors when i tried those suggestions(might just be my compiler or something, but also i need to do it without using a sorting algorithm.

Comment: You can't sort without a sorting algorithm :)

Comment: @dudicus - Why `std::sort` is not good enough?  Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @dudicus at this point you are more or less just spamming SO with the same assignment, consider this that the amount of time someone will put in to answer your question and help you is proportional to the amount of time and effort you spend to prepare your question.

Comment: @Casper Von B, yes this is a homework assignment.So we can only use what we've covered in class so no vectors or sorting algorithms  Sorry, i'm not trying to spam, i'm new to this site and programming in general. I just would like to know what should be done in my "sort_by_age" function in order to print out the data from oldest to youngest.

Comment: You'll always get a pragmatic answer, i suppose the question you really have is how do i implement 'Y' sorting algorithm in C++ and apply that to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::sort`, preferably with a lambda, for example.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct employee {
   int social_security_id;
   int date_of_birth;
   string first_name;
   string last_name;
   string state;
};

// parses and returns a vector of employees from the given stream.
std::vector<employee> parse_employees(ifstream ifs)
{
   std::string str;
   std::vector<employee> v;

   while (!ifs.eof()) {
      employee e;

      ifs >> e.social_security_id >> e.date_of_birth >> e.first_name >> e.last_name >> e.state;

      v.push_back(e);
   }

   return v;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   ifstream ifs("/home/www/class/een118/labs/database1.txt");
   auto employees = parse_employees(ifs);

   std::sort( std::begin(employees), std::end(employees),
      []( const employees &a, const employees &b )
      {
         return ( a.date_of_birth > b.date_of_birth );
      });

   for (auto e : v) {
      cout << e.social_security_id << e.date_of_birth << e.first_name << e.last_name << endl;
   }
}
```